# how to delete an entry from azure sql?

Tags: sql, azure

here is screenshot from my azure sql database. I would like to remove user Nazerke. I've deleted the row, and when I wanted to save it, it gives me " Incorrect syntax near WHERE" as you can see on the top of database. How can I delete the user and what could be possible solution?[image]

Comment: The screenshot is not legible - can you please post your actual SQL command you've tried to use?

Comment: I haven't written any query. Just selected row -> pressed "Delete row" -> pressed "Save"

Comment: @marc_s you can see the full image by following this url: http://i.stack.imgur.com/9Wcx0.png

Comment: Write a TSQL command to drop the row using the GUID?

Comment: When I say "DROP USER "XXX" "  it says "Cannot drop the user 'XXX', because it does not exist or you do not have permission."
Where can I change permission for the service account to delete entries from table

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the password contains weird characters, maybe the Silverlight application has issues supporting these (don't know for sure). Could you try to delete an other record, like the user with username **JDuck**?

**Update:** The actual solution can be found in this question: [how to change permission for the service account in azure's sql management portal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13662752/how-to-change-permission-for-the-service-account-in-azures-sql-management-porta/13663466#13663466)

Answer (score 0):

This is just a user defined table that you created? Just delete the row: `delete from [dbo].[Users] where Guid = '<guid>'`