# how to change permission for the service account in azure's sql management portal

Tags: sql, azure, permissions, sql-drop

I want to delete an entry from my sql table, through Azure's sql management portal. When I query "DROP USER "XXX" "  it says "Cannot drop the user 'XXX', because it does not exist or you do not have permission."
Where can I change permission for the service account to delete entries from table?
[image: This user does exist]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming this question is related to your previous question ([how to delete an entry from azure sql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13661688/how-to-delete-an-entry-from-azure-sql)). `DROP USER` will try to remove a user which has access to your database, this has nothing to do with removing a record from the Users table. To remove a record from the users table, execute the following query:

```
DELETE FROM dbo.Users WHERE Username = 'Nazerke'
```

Comment: yes. It seemed to me it should be separate question, so I created new thread. You are right, I want to delete entry from database not a user which has access to my database. 
I tried your suggestion. NOw it says: 
"The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_InstitutionUser_User". The conflict occurred in database "PasteurDatabase", table "dbo.InstitutionUser", column 'InstitutionUser_Institution_Guid'."

Comment: This means your database still contains records that are related to that specific user record. Try removing all records in the InstituationUser table first which reference the ID of the Nazerke user in the Users table.